# Technology during Days of Moshiach

Tags: technology, messiah, olam-haba-world-to-come

When Moshisch comes (Biezras Hashem) will there be technology like, computers, cars, electricity, etc?

Comment: Few consider yemei mashiach to be Olam haba.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmlTHfVaU9o&feature=related somewhere in his videos I believe he tells a story about how he was in heaven and he was listening to his favorite rapper.

Comment: Times of Mashiach and times of Olam Haba are different, title should be changed.

Comment: According to some, we are currently in the time period referred to as ‘the Days of Moshiach’. So the answer would be, yes.

Answer (score 13):

The Rambam in [Hilchot Milachim 12:1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/e512.htm) says "OLAM KMINHAGO HOLECH." The world will continue as is including electronics.In fact the Chofetz Chaim said that most of today's technology it proves the point for example he said until phones no one could understand how Hashem could hear all so Hashem showed us an example.

Answer (score 0):

We do not know what will be in the time of mashiach, except that it will be *olam haba* in *olam haza*.

Comment: Now that the hills of Judea bear fruit, and a plurality of the Jewish people are back in Israel, I think we can get an inkling :)

Comment: How do you know this?